# FetchError: invalid json response body at <domain-name>/api/content/types/ reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, next.js, build, aws-amplify

I am building an application using NextJs. Locally if I run `npm run dev` it is working fine. Locally when I try to run the build using `npm run build` it is not working as there is localhost URL but now I am trying to deploy the application on AWS amplify with their default domain. My .env file looks like:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT=<domain-name>/api
NODE_ENV=production
MONGODB_URI=<url of Cloud based MongoDB>
```

Many developers also facing the same problem and I have tried by implementing their solutions too but still I am getting same error if I build the project. My project directory looks like:

[project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuRNc.png)

and my `getStaticPaths()` code is

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const contentTypes = await loadContentTypes();

  const playlists = await loadPlaylist();

  const paths = [];

  contentTypes.forEach((type) => {
    paths.push({
      params: {
        type,
      },
    });
  });


  playlists.forEach((playlist) => {
    paths.push({
      params: {
        type: playlist._id,
      },
    });
  });

  // All missing paths are going to be server-side rendered and cached
  return { paths, fallback: true };
}
```

and `getStaticProps()` is

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  const data = await loadContent(context);
  const contentTypes = await loadContentTypes();

  let contentType = "";

  // Content Type definition
  for (let i = 0; i < contentTypes.length; i++) {
    if (contentTypes[i] === context.params.type) {
      contentType = contentTypes[i];
      break;
    }

    contentType = "playlist";
  }

  const title = defineTitle(contentType, data);
  const tags = findTags(data);

  return {
    props: { data, title, contentType, tags },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

definition of `loadPlaylist()` is:

```
import fetch from '../utils/fetcher';
    
export async function loadPlaylist() {
    
  const data = await fetch(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/playlists/bnb`
  );
    
  return data
}
```

definition of `loadContentTypes()` is:

```
import fetch from '../utils/fetcher';
    
export async function loadContentTypes() {
    
  const data = await fetch(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/content/types`
  );
    
  return data
}
```

fetcher definition is:

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

export default async function Fetcher(...args) {
  const res = await fetch(...args,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        // update with your user-agent
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "User-Agent": "*", 
        Accept: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      }
    });
  return res.json();
}
```

the error message is: [error while building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/422wU.jpg)

Comment: You are trying to parse a html response to json. Please try to log the response.

Comment: @AshutoshPatole thank you for your response. For this problem, I have added the header in my fetcher but if still this is the issue then what is solution?

Comment: Your request is most likely failing for some reason. If you log `res` to the console inside the `Fetcher` function, what's the output?

Comment: Thank you everyone. It turned out that I have to separate the APIs from the project and deploy somewhere(locally or on server) so that during the build, the APIs endpoints can be reached